# How to get TinyMCE to show Font-Family for text not in a span

Tags: tinymce-4

I notice that the Font Family button in TinyMCE shows the actual font-family of selected text - *IF* you've set the font family previously for that text with the Font Family button.

So in the image at the left below I've selected "some" and set it to Comic Sans with the standard TinyMCE Font Family button. Once I've done that, selecting "some" shows the Comic Sans font in the Font Family button. But selecting another word in the line that hasn't had it's font-family changed doesn't show it's font-family. (See right image.)

[image: Comic]  [image]

I know that setting font-famly puts the selection in a `<span>` that has that font-family style, so that appears to be the rule for showing the font-family:  if it's specified in a `<span>` for the selection, it gets shown, otherwise selecting the text doesn't show its font-family.

I want to change this behavior so that when you select a word, its font is displayed in the Font Family button, whether the text is in a span or not.

Does anyone have any ideas for doing that?

Thanks

Comment: TinyMCE 4.6.1 (latest) seems to do what you describe in my testing.  What version are you using?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out!  I'm still running 4.1.7.  I'll update right away.